# Formatar valor de um tabela

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma tabela que recebo os dados de datas neste formato: `-'06/05/2019 09:07:34` e `-'06/05/2019` sempre com esses caracteres `-'`.

Gostaria de formatar os valores das colunas de data para `06/05/2019 09:07:34` e `06/05/2019`.

```css
        tbody {
            font-size: 11px;
            color: #bdbdbd;

        }

        input {
            color: #bdbdbd;
        }

        th {
            color: #bdbdbd;

        }


        table.striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd) {

            background-color: #293a46;

        }

        body {
            background: url(http://seac-pr.com.br/content/uploads/2014/05/INTERSEP.png) #1a2224;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }



        .input-field input[type=text]:focus+label,
        .materialize-textarea:focus:not([readonly])+label {
            color: #b7c3d0 !important;
        }


        .input-field input[type=text]:focus,
        .materialize-textarea:focus:not([readonly]) {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #b7c3d0 !important;
            box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #b7c3d0 !important;
        }

        .blackIcon {
            color: #000;
        }

        .greenIcon {
            color: green;
        }

        .rBlueIcon {
            color: royalblue;
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 1px solid #A4A4A4;
        }

        table td {
            border: 1px solid #A4A4A4;
        }

        table.highlight>tbody>tr:hover {
            background-color: #2E5C78;
        }

        table.highlight>tbody>tr {
            color: white;
        }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  
    <base target="_top">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
   
</head>

<body>

            <table class="highlight">
                <thead>

                    <tr>
                        <th>ID REGISTRO</th>
                        <th>Data e hora do Registro</th>
                        <th>Data da falta</th>
    
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody id="coportoTabela">

                    <tr>
                        <td>COD1557144453513</td>
                        <td>-'06/05/2019 09:07:34</td>
                        <td>-'06/05/2019</td>
                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>COD1557148342924</td>
                        <td>-'06/05/2019 10:12:23</td>
                        <td>-'06/05/2019</td>
                        
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>



        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Por favor nos mostre o código javascript.

Comment: De onde vem esses dados???
Penso que é necessário ver o backend para tentar solucionar o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar:

```
    function formatDate(date) {
        var d = new Date(date),
day = '' + d.getDate(),
            month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),

            year = d.getFullYear();

        if (month.length < 2) 
            month = '0' + month;
        if (day.length < 2) 
            day = '0' + day;

        return [day, month, year].join('-');
    }
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
alert(formatDate('Sun Fev 20,2020'));
```

Rsultado:

20-02-2020

Mas o ideal é você mostrar seu Javascript.

Comment: eu consegui remover os dois primeiros caracteres usando o " .slice(2) " dentro do Array das datas